# Change value in the date field

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm need your help!)

I have use in my project the field with date. Them i'm fill with django values date :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker()
        .datetimepicker({value:'{{ now_date|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}',step:10});
</script>
```

It's cool, but have trouble with changing time. Because now was show date only when site was loaded and don't changed (so need refresh the page every one minute, but i don't must do this)
How i can do, what the date can change every minute?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to `change the date` or `keep as it is` when the page is being refreshed every one minute ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get now datetime using javascript only.
Write function, which will reinitialize datetimepicker with current time, put it in `setInterval` with 1 minute interval.